# What is the correct way to call this OpenCV function from Python?

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I would like to use the selective search algorithm to segment images into possible object locations. I found that the library I already use for computer vision, OpenCV, implements this functionality as shown in the documentation [here](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/dc/d7a/classcv_1_1ximgproc_1_1segmentation_1_1SelectiveSearchSegmentationStrategy.html). However, I'm using Python and not C++, so I looked through OpenCV's github repositories until I found the [example](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/ximgproc/samples/selectivesearchsegmentation_demo.py) that I reproduced below.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

'''
A program demonstrating the use and capabilities of a particular image segmentation algorithm described
in Jasper R. R. Uijlings, Koen E. A. van de Sande, Theo Gevers, Arnold W. M. Smeulders:
    "Selective Search for Object Recognition"
International Journal of Computer Vision, Volume 104 (2), page 154-171, 2013
Usage:
    ./selectivesearchsegmentation_demo.py input_image (single|fast|quality)
Use "a" to display less rects, 'd' to display more rects, "q" to quit.
'''

import cv2
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    img = cv2.imread(sys.argv[1])

    cv2.setUseOptimized(True)
    cv2.setNumThreads(8)

    gs = cv2.ximgproc.segmentation.createSelectiveSearchSegmentation()
    gs.setBaseImage(img)

    if (sys.argv[2][0] == 's'):
        gs.switchToSingleStrategy()

    elif (sys.argv[2][0] == 'f'):
        gs.switchToSelectiveSearchFast()

    elif (sys.argv[2][0] == 'q'):
        gs.switchToSelectiveSearchQuality()
    else:
        print(__doc__)
        sys.exit(1)

    rects = gs.process()
    nb_rects = 10

    while True:
        wimg = img.copy()

        for i in range(len(rects)):
            if (i < nb_rects):
                x, y, w, h = rects[i]
                cv2.rectangle(wimg, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)

        cv2.imshow("Output", wimg);
        c = cv2.waitKey()

        if (c == 100):
            nb_rects += 10

        elif (c == 97 and nb_rects > 10):
            nb_rects -= 10

        elif (c == 113):
            break

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Unfortunately, running this program with the command `python selective_search.py "/home/christopher/DroneKit/Vision/Face Detection/Annotated Faces in the Wild/originalPics/2002/07/19/big/img_135.jpg"  f` gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "selective_search.py", line 37, in <module>
    rects = gs.process()
TypeError: Required argument 'rects' (pos 1) not found
```

Based upon that error message, I figured maybe I could just pass it a Python list and then the underlying C++ function would fill it with the algorithm's output. However, when I excecuted the following code:

```
rects = []
gs.process(rects)
print(rects)
```

The output was an empty list, and the image was displayed with no rectangles drawn on it. Therefore, I am at a loss on how I should call `gs.process()`. If it helps, the C++ declaration of the function is

```
CV_WRAP virtual void process(CV_OUT std::vector<Rect>& rects) = 0;
```

(Edit) Additional information copied from the comments:

Output from `help(gs.process)`:

```
process(...) method of cv2.ximgproc_segmentation_SelectiveSearchSegmentation instance process(rects) -> None. rects = gs.process(rects) just makes rects None and causes the program to terminate with an exception
```

Using `rects = gs.process(rects)` sets rects to `None` and causes the program to terminate with an exception.

OpenCV version is 3.2.0.

Using a numpy array instead of a python list crashes my program with the following message:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (channels() == CV_MAT_CN(dtype)) in copyTo, file /home/christopher/opencv/modules/core/src/copy.cpp, line 259
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /home/christopher/opencv/modules/core/src/copy.cpp:259: error: (-215) channels() == CV_MAT_CN(dtype) in function copyTo

Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: Try `help(gs.process)` and see what it tells you. IIRC `CV_WRAP` with `CV_OUT` parameter means that in Python it will be an argument, as well as one of the return values. Usually the argument is optional, but I guess this is a proof that not always. Hence I would expect you want `rects = gs.process(rects)`.

Comment: @Dan Mašek process(...) method of cv2.ximgproc_segmentation_SelectiveSearchSegmentation instance
    process(rects) -> None. `rects = gs.process(rects)` just makes rects None and causes the program to terminate with an exception.

Comment: What if you try to pass a numpy array instead of a Python list? What version of OpenCV is this?

Comment: @Dan Mašek It's OpenCV 3.2.0. Using `rects = np.array([]);
    gs.process(rects)` crashes my program with the following message `OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (channels() == CV_MAT_CN(dtype)) in copyTo, file /home/christopher/opencv/modules/core/src/copy.cpp, line 259
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /home/christopher/opencv/modules/core/src/copy.cpp:259: error: (-215) channels() == CV_MAT_CN(dtype) in function copyTo

Aborted (core dumped)`

Comment: Interesting -- [edit] the question and add all this useful information. I'm kinda baffled right now. It might be worth paying a visit to the [`opencv_contrib` issue tracker](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/issues/) and creating a ticket. At the least it deserves some clarification in the documentation, or there may be a problem that needs fixing. Give it a shot.

Comment: @Dan Mašek Created a ticket: https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/issues/1312

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the version of OpenCV 3.2.0 that I compiled for Python was missing this [fix](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/commit/83fef80343cbc05681584f2af82a895f10efbd3b) locally. I went ahead and recompiled my python bindings using the [latest stable release](http://opencv.org/releases.html) of OpenCV 3.3.0 and the latest changes to the OpenCV contrib repository and the sample script worked as expected after that.